# Standard way to show "empty ui" loading in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, lightning-web-components

Is it possible to use standard functionality to show empty component on loading (instead of loading spinner)? For example in lead convert mapping we can see empty table and then all data inside:
[image: empty loading table]

Comment: If you extract the SVG's from the HTML you could use them to create a custom loading layer based on [this](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/spinners/#site-main-content)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like this is going to have to be implemented by you for now.

Look at this issue on the lightning design github.

https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/issues/193

Latest comment from Salesforce I could find. Back in Apr'18.

> Stencils are not built through the Design System. While we'd love to get to them, we've had some pretty big projects lately, so they have continued to fall below the line.
>
> That said, we're gonna publish you a roadmap! We can't promise when things will get done, but we can at least give you a basic priority order...